# Al subir al servidor hay un query que no funciona

Tags: php, html, mysqli

estaba trabajando una web en el local, ahora la e subido al servidor porque las programaciones que me quedan necesito que este subida en el servidor. Bien al subirla al servidor del cliente funciona todo perfecto menos una página que no me carga los querys. Lo bueno es que si la subo a mi servidor si que funciona todo correcto, entonces no se que puede ser, subo el código que creo que falla por si veis alguna anomalia.

```
<?php include "conexion/conexion.php" ?>

<?php include ("includes/nav.php")?>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
         <div class="col-12" style="z-index:2;">
           <h4 class="tituEquip" id="TituPorque">Depilación Depildiodo</h4>
           <h2 class="padBtonConoce tituEquip" id="TituPorque2">¿Que tipo de equipo necesitas? </h2>
           <a href="#" id="botonPorque" class="btonConoce toc">¿Por qué tener Depilación Láser en mi centro?</a>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>


<div class="col-12 padLosEquipos">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-7 txt7">
        <h3>Consigue evolucionar tu negocio</h3>
        <h5>en tan sólo 4 pasos</h5>
        <p>Consigue más clientes para tu centro durante todo el año 
           <strong>(incluso en verano)</strong>. Descubre las ventajas del equipo más recomendado para la depilación por la comunidad científica. 
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="detall22"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up falista2259"></i> Trabaja también en verano</div>
        <div class="detall22"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up falista2259" style="animation-delay: 0.5s;" ></i> Cualquier fototipo de piel</div>
        <div class="detall22"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up falista2259" style="animation-delay: 0.7s;" ></i> Servicio técnico</div>
        <div class="detall22"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up falista2259" style="animation-delay: 0.9s;" ></i> Soporte formativo</div>
        <!--<div class="detall22"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up falista2259"></i> Formación incluida</div>-->
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

**Aquí es donde creo que falla, porque uno de los errores es que no carga la imagen.**

```
<div class="col-12 PdPnn corrigPadfff">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">

      <?php
       //var_dump($_GET);
       $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM productos 
                                 WHERE estado = 1");
       mysqli_set_charset("utf8");

       //resultado del query
       $result;
       //variable de control
       $variablecontrol = 0;
        foreach ($result as $itemregistro){
            if ($variablecontrol%2==0){
       ?>
       <div id="Norecomen" class="col-4">
       <div id="boxicing2" class="mod-maqLos" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
       <div style="position: relative;">
          <div class="titulosPOs">
             <h5><?php echo $itemregistro['producto']; ?></h5>
             <h2 class="chaDos"><?php echo $itemregistro['alias']; ?></h2>
             <img src="images/maquinas/<?php echo $itemregistro['imagen']; ?>" alt="" id="imGDio" class="iMgDiod">
          </div>
          <div class="row margBOO">
            <div class="col-6">
            <div id="nAlquilar" class="col-6 pvp" style="padding-left: 0px;">435<small>€/mes</small><div class="desdesmall LEft">desde</div><div class="siniva" style="width: 100%;">Precio sin IVA</div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6"><a href="equipos.php?ID=1" class="btn btn-primary bonton-info ">ME INTERESA</a></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <?php } else{ ?>

     <div id="recomendado" class="col-8">
       <div id="boxicing1"  class="mod-maqLos2" >
         <div style="position: relative;">
            <div class="titulosPOs1">                        
              <?php $it= $itemregistro['id']; ?>

              <h5><?php echo $itemregistro['producto']; ?><p class="pLab">¡ EL + ALQUILADO !</p></h5>
              <h2 class="dualwavefont cahDoa"><?php echo $itemregistro['alias']; ?></h2>

              <div class="row GmBton">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="paDEspec">
              <?php
              $resultas = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM checks 
                                       WHERE IDproducto = $it");
              mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
              while($resa = $resultas->fetch_array()) {
              ?>               
              <div class="fetAlla"><i class="fas fa-check-circle fastRer"></i> <?php echo $resa['titulo']; ?></div>                 
              <?php } ?>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
               <img src="images/maquinas/<?php echo $itemregistro['imagen']; ?>" alt="" id="imgDual" class="imgDUal">
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
            <div class="row margBOO">
               <div class="col-6">
               <div id="nAlquilar" class="col-6 pvp" style="padding-left: 0px;">455<small>€/mes</small><div class="desdesmall LEft">desde</div><div class="siniva" style="width: 100%;">Precio sin IVA</div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6"><a href="equipos.php?ID=2" class="btn btn-primary bonton-info ">ME INTERESA</a></div>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>

        <?php
              }
             $variablecontrol++;
          }
        ?>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: ¿Te da algún error en el log? Dices que uno de los errores es que no muestra las imágenes, ¿puedes poner el código generado en lugar del php?

Comment: Hola @JaviMollá un placer saludarte de nuevo, solo me devuelve el error de las imagenes, en el console no sale nada más. A que te refieres con el codigo generado??

Comment: Al html y css que ves en el navegador

Comment: Viendolo un poco por encima veo que tienes una línea con solo `$result;`Puede ser que pueda ir por ahi el error.

Comment: mira puedes entrar aquí: http://webnueva.depildiodo.com/los-equipos.php

Comment: El caso es que la consulta no te devuelve el nombre de la imagen desde php.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por las respuestas, perdonar pero sali de viaje a Madrid y no pude probar nada, he visto lo de la linea `$result;` pero añadi lo que pone el compañero abajo y tampoco funciona...

Comment: Como puede ser que en el local si que funcione y en otro servidor que tengo también??

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código html y css generado, tal cual lo ves tu en el navegador? Sobre todo las líneas donde se muestran las imágenes

Comment: Buenas @JaviMollá no es mucho código para pegarlo aquí??? te lo comento por que en la URL puedes verla

Comment: Ok, lo acabo de ver. Una de las rutas que debería mostrar una imagen apunta a un recurso, no a una imagen: `<img src="images/maquinas/1" alt="" id="imGDio" class="iMgDiod">`. Verás que esto se resuelve como la url: http://webnueva.depildiodo.com/images/maquinas/1 que es una página completa, con errores, por cierto

Comment: Claro esque no deberia apuntar a esta ruta, es decir el 1 ese no es correcto, creo que lo que no funciona nada es la consulta que se hacer con `$itemregistro`

Comment: Mira @JaviMollá chequeala aquí y veras como esta correcto http://josevishosteleria.com/los-equipos.php

Comment: Ya pero ves que lo que te ha generado es distinto: `<img src="images/maquinas/diodo.png" alt="" id="imGDio" class="iMgDiod" style="right: -18%; transition: all 1s ease 0s;">`

Comment: Pero esta todo exactamente igual en un servidor que en el otro! :S

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83887/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-miguel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta traerte los resultados al formato de array con `fetch_array()`, como lo haces al traerte la query de resultas.

```
$results= $results->fetch_array();
```

**Edito tu respuesta para mostrar la solución final!**

Simplemente cambiamos esto:

```
foreach ($result as $itemregistro){
```

Por esto otro:

```
while ($res = $result->fetch_array()) {
```

Supongo por lo que hable con @Javi sera por las versiones de PHP

Comment: Buenas, he probado lo que me comentas pero tampoco sale nada...

Comment: Veo que ahora por lo menos te carga unos números. Ahora comprueba que la ruta de las imágenes están bien y si la query en base de datos trae los datos adecuados.

Comment: Si por lo que veo esta correcto tanto la query como las rutas, de hecho en el local y en otro servidor funciona correcto

Comment: Por lo que veo en el código me saca todo el rato un numero 1

Comment: Te saca lo que hay en ese campo en esa base de datos

Comment: Igual tienes mal la base de datos

Comment: Las bd son identicas!